# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator, whats wrong?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

**Send to Email.java**

```
package helper;

//Mail.java - smtp sending starttls (ssl) authentication enabled
//1.Open a new Java class in netbeans (default package of the project) and name it as "Mail.java"
//2.Copy paste the entire code below and save it.
//3.Right click on the file name in the left side panel and click "compile" then click "Run"

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class sendToEmail
{
    String  d_email = "sample@gmail.com",
     d_password = "mysamplepassword",
     d_host = "smtp.gmail.com",
     d_port  = "465",
     //m_to = "sample@yahoo.com",
     m_subject = "trial",
     m_text = "Hey, this is the testing email.";

    public sendToEmail(String strEmailAddress)
    {


        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", d_email);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", d_host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", d_port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        //props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", d_port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();

        try
        {
            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
            //session.setDebug(true);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setText(m_text);
            msg.setSubject(m_subject);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(d_email));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(strEmailAddress));
            Transport.send(msg);
        }
        catch (Exception mex)
        {
            mex.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    public class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator
    {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
        {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(d_email, d_password);
        }
    }
}
```

**portion of my controller.java**

```
/* Send to Email will run properly soon */
            sendToEmail email = new sendToEmail(strEmailAddress);
```

When I run my web application I got this error message saying:

> Type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an
>   internal error () that prevented it
>   from fulfilling this request.
>
> exception 
>   javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   Servlet execution threw an exception
>
> root cause 
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   javax/mail/Authenticator
>     controller.RegisterTenantController.doPost(RegisterTenantController.java:108)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)

What will I do now? Can somebody help me to get this web application successful?

Answer (score 53):

You need to add two jars into the WEB-INF/lib directory or your webapp (or lib directory of the server):

- [mail.jar](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/mail/1.4.1/mail-1.4.1.jar) - contains the actual smtp implmentation
- [activation.jar](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1.1/activation-1.1.1.jar) - needed by mail.jar

Answer (score 27):

While it's possible that this is due to a jar file missing from your classpath, it may not be.

It is important to keep two or three different exceptions strait in our head in this case:

1. **`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`**  This exception indicates that the class was not found on the classpath.  This indicates that we were trying to load the class definition, and the class did not exist on the classpath.
2. **`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`**  This exception indicates that the JVM looked in its internal class definition data structure for the definition of a class and did not find it.  This is different than saying that it could not be loaded from the classpath.  Usually this indicates that we previously attempted to load a class from the classpath, but it failed for some reason - now we're trying again, but we're not even going to try to load it, because we failed loading it earlier.  The earlier failure could be a `ClassNotFoundException` or an `ExceptionInInitializerError` (indicating a failure in the static initialization block) or any number of other problems.  The point is, a `NoClassDefFoundError` is not necessarily a classpath problem.

I would look at the source for `javax.mail.Authenticator`, and see what it is doing in it's static initializer. (Look at static variable initialization and the static block, if there is one.)  If you aren't getting a `ClassNotFoundException` prior to the `NoClassDefFoundError`, you're almost guaranteed that it's a static initialization problem.

I have seen similar errors quite frequently when the hosts file incorrectly defines the localhost address, and the static initialization block relies on `InetAddress.getLocalHost()`. 127.0.0.1 should point to 'localhost' (and probably also localhost.localdomain). It should NOT point to the actual host name of the machine (although for some reason, many older RedHat Linux installers liked to set it incorrectly).

Answer (score 24):

Add following to your maven dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: with javax mail 1.5.2  I face the error [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger

Comment: To browse the latest versions see [javax.mail](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22javax.mail%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mail%22) & [javax.activation](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22javax.activation%22%20AND%20a%3A%22activation%22)

Answer (score 8):

I once ran into this situation and I had the dependencies in classpath. The solution was to include javax.mail and javax.activation libraries in the container's (eg. tomcat) lib folder. Using maven -set them to **provided** scope and it should work. You will have shared email libs in classpath for all projects.

Useful source: http://haveacafe.wordpress.com/2008/09/26/113/

Answer (score 4):

When I had this problem, I had included the `mail-api.jar` in my maven pom file.  That's the API specification *only*.  The fix is to replace this:

```
<!-- DO NOT USE - it's just the API, not an implementation -->
<groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
```

with the reference implementation of that api:

```
<groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
```

I know it has sun in the package name, but that's the latest version.  I learned this from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28935760/1128668

Answer (score 1):

Even I was facing a similar error. Try below 2 steps (the first of which has been recommended here already) - 
 1. Add the dependencies to your `pom.xml`

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. If that doesn't work, manually place the `jar` files in your `.m2\repository\javax\<folder>\<version>\` directory.

Answer (score 1):

When running with `com.sun.mail` group, version `1.6.2` under a Servlet environment, notice that artifact:

- `mailapi` contains `javax.mail.Authenticator` but *not* the 'provider' classes
- `javax.mail` contains both `javax.mail.Authenticator` *and all* the `sun.com.mail` 'provider` classes (SMTP, IMAP and POP3)
- `smtp` (and `imap` and `pop3`) don't contain `javax.mail.Authenticator` ... *just* each `com.sun.mail.*` provider on its own

Now, if one didn't want IMAP and POP3 (since these are client protocols for *fetching* email) but *just* SMTP for sending, you want `javamail-1.6.2.jar` and `smtp-1.6.2.jar`.

Now in a Servlet environment, realise that you can either choose 'use what the container provides' or 'supply my own'.  So you either place both those JAR files in the Container's 'common' runtime, or you supply both those JAR files in your own `WEB-INF\lib` directory ... and it will work.

What you *can't* do is put `javamail-1.6.2.jar` into your `WEB-INF\lib` and `smtp-1.6.2.jar` into your `$TOMCAT_HOME/lib`.  Why not?  Because, [class-loader hierarchy](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html).  The SMTP provider needs the `javax.mail` classes.  But (unlike , significantly, `java.sql`), the `javax.mail` classes are not loaded by the system classloader 'further up' or even 'at the same level' ... they're loaded by a classloader that's specific to YOUR webapp on 'one of the branches down'!  So when the SMTP provider wants a `javax.mail` class, it doesn't find one, because the 'common to everyone' classloader has no business looking into individual webapps to load the required classes!

So either:

- use `javax.mail-1.6.2.jar` and no other JavaMail JARs; OR
- use both `javamail-1.6.2.jar` with `smtp-1.6.2.jar`

but always put these *all* in the Server's common libraries  OR  *all* in your web-app's common libraries.

Which stance you adopt depends on you.  There are pros and cons each way.  Classes you supply in `WEB-INF\libs` are always going to 'win', in case you need to defeat an older version loaded as 'common' by the Server.  But that may not be a great idea, always.