# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger for JUnit test case for Java mail

Tags: java, junit, jakarta-mail

I am using Java Mail API to read and parse emails. It is working fine with Servlet code.

Now I am trying to write a JUnit test case for the same purpose. But on line  `Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);` I am getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/MailLogger
    at javax.mail.Session.initLogger(Session.java:227)
    at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:212)
    at javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:315)
    at javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(Session.java:355)
    at com.vxl.appanalytix.dataload.fromEmail.EmailParser.parseEmailSubject(EmailParser.java:44)
    at com.vxl.appanalytix.controllers.controllerClasses.GenericEmailServiceClass.readEmailAttachments(GenericEmailServiceClass.java:33)
    at com.vxl.appanalytix.dataload.GenericEmailTestCase.test(GenericEmailTestCase.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 35 more
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

`com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger` is part of [JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) API. It is already included in EE environment (that's why you can use it on your live server), but it is not included in SE environment.

[Oracle docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html):

> The JavaMail API is available as an optional package for use with Java
>   SE platform and is also included in the Java EE platform.

99% that you run your tests in SE environment which means what you have to bother about adding it manually to your classpath when running tests.

If you're using maven add the following dependency (you might want to change version):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The javax.mail-api artifact is only good for compiling against.  You actually need to run code, so you need a complete implementation of JavaMail.  Use `<groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId><artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>`.

Comment: No longer works...
Could not find com.sun.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/sun/mail/javax.mail-api/1.6.0/javax.mail-api-1.6.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/sun/mail/javax.mail-api/1.6.0/javax.mail-api-1.6.0.pom
       - https://splunk.jfrog.io/splunk/ext-releases-local/com/sun/mail/javax.mail-api/1.6.0/javax.mail-api-1.6.0.pom

Answer (score 193):

The `javax.mail-api` artifact is only good for *compiling* against.

You actually need to ***run*** code, so you need a complete *implementation* of JavaMail API. Use this:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

NOTE: The version number will probably differ. Check the latest version [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail).

Comment: This also fixes `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/PropUtil` as well as `Could not initialize class javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress` errors.

Comment: It's explained on the [JavaMail project web page](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_Release).

Comment: THANK YOUx100. That is all.

Answer (score 55):

I use the following maven dependencies to get java mail working. The first one includes the javax.mail API (with no implementation) and the second one is the SUN implementation of the javax.mail API.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You don't need to include the api if you have the implementation.

Comment: Good point @GlenPeterson, I didn't realise that from the solution above but when I looked into the com.sun.mail jar the javax.mail api is included in it.

Answer (score 4):

Download this JAR and add it to your libraries: http://java.net/projects/javamail/downloads/download/javax.mail.jar

Answer (score 3):

Please see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/, you can download jar or use the maven dependency, depending on your project type. That should pretty much cover it and you won't get a NoClassDefFoundError exception.

Answer (score 2):

Really it's interesting. You need just use  javax-mail.jar of "com.sun"  not "javax.mail".
[dwonload com.sun mail jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by uninstalling

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and installing

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

You **cannot** use these two packages together as they incur a `java.lang.module.ResolutionException` - there is some sort of conflict with JUnit packages.

If you're curious about my versions,

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens also if your code is expecting Java Mail 1.4 and your jars are Java Mail 1.3. Happened to me when upgraded Pentaho Kettle

Regards