# NetBeans not seeing javax

Tags: netbeans, dependencies, jar-with-dependencies

I have a servlet & a class sitting in the same package on a NetBeans web project.
(these class locations are for example only-- 
this is nowhere near my ideal organization of classes.)

In the servlet, everything is alright-- it is seeing javax and whatever i'm looking for in it.

However, in the plain java class, it's not even recognizing the imports-- giving me "Package javax.* does not exist" let alone fixing the imports itself.

What's missing here?

**EDIT:** I've seen [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/Authenticator, whats wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630002/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-mail-authenticator-whats-wrong) along with some other discussions.

Comment: It might be something out of sync, try clearing [Netbeans cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8689780/how-to-clear-the-cache-in-netbeans).

Answer (score 0):

Added the javax.mail jars to the project lib.

Netbeans must be using the libraries depending on the type of the project and the classes