# Sending email from android app using SMTP

Tags: java, android, email, smtp

I have been working on android mailing using google SMTP , i was running this tutorials code to run this program ,i ran the exact same program, but i have been getting crash on my app.
I have been running this on emulator.

http://javapapers.com/android/android-email-app-with-gmail-smtp-using-javamail/

Can you tell whats the problem here, i am kind of new to this.

Logcat

```
11-18 00:20:56.252: I/SendMailTask(1285): About to instantiate GMail...
11-18 00:20:56.262: I/dalvikvm(1285): Could not find method javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance, referenced from method com.javapapers.android.androidjavamail.GMail.createEmailMessage
11-18 00:20:56.262: W/dalvikvm(1285): VFY: unable to resolve static method 90: Ljavax/mail/Session;.getDefaultInstance (Ljava/util/Properties;Ljavax/mail/Authenticator;)Ljavax/mail/Session;
11-18 00:20:56.262: D/dalvikvm(1285): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
11-18 00:20:56.262: I/dalvikvm(1285): Could not find method javax.mail.Session.getTransport, referenced from method com.javapapers.android.androidjavamail.GMail.sendEmail
11-18 00:20:56.262: W/dalvikvm(1285): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 91: Ljavax/mail/Session;.getTransport (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/mail/Transport;
11-18 00:20:56.262: D/dalvikvm(1285): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0004
11-18 00:20:56.262: D/dalvikvm(1285): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0061 at 0x0d in Lcom/javapapers/android/androidjavamail/GMail;.createEmailMessage
11-18 00:20:56.262: D/dalvikvm(1285): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0060 at 0x1a in Lcom/javapapers/android/androidjavamail/GMail;.createEmailMessage
11-18 00:20:56.262: D/dalvikvm(1285): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x005f at 0x66 in Lcom/javapapers/android/androidjavamail/GMail;.createEmailMessage
11-18 00:20:56.262: I/GMail(1285): Mail server properties set.
11-18 00:20:56.412: I/Choreographer(1285): Skipped 87 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 00:20:56.732: I/Choreographer(1285): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 00:20:56.912: I/Choreographer(1285): Skipped 88 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 00:20:56.992: I/Choreographer(1285): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-18 00:20:57.122: W/dalvikvm(1285): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2aa8ba8)
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285): Process: com.javapapers.android.androidjavamail, PID: 1285
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.mail.Session
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at com.javapapers.android.androidjavamail.GMail.createEmailMessage(GMail.java:58)
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at com.javapapers.android.androidjavamail.SendMailTask.doInBackground(SendMailTask.java:37)
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-18 00:20:57.752: E/AndroidRuntime(1285):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: You're missing your dependencies. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1630106/2093246 
Also take a look at the tutorial link, there's a step all the way at the bottom telling you what you need to do.

Comment: i have actually added these 3  jar files from android project properties , but seems like program is still not working

Comment: Are you sure you're doing this correctly? Android has a big problem importing libraries if not done right. Make sure the folder you place them in are inside your project and it's called "libs"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a

Comment: nope , jar files added fine , still couldn't figure out , why its not working.