# Android Studio: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, session, gradle, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to build an app that sends an email using javamail and gmail's smtp service, but when I run it it crashes when I call Session.getInstance. After debugging it appears that it's a NoClassDefFoundError regarding com.sun.mail.util.MailLogger. I read [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30808562/java-lang-noclassdeffound-error-javax-gmail-api) that I had to add an older mail package in order to get it, but I'm still getting errors.

Here's what I have in Android Studio:

```
 // Get system properties
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();

    // Setup mail server
    properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.put("mail.transport.protocol","smtp");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    authenticator = getAuthenticator();
    /* What getAuthenticator looks like:
    return new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("myemail@gmail.com ", "password");
        }
    };
    */

    // Get the default Session object, with authentication
    try {
        session = Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
    } catch (Error e) {
        // Unnecessary code for debugging
        int hold = 0;
    }

    // Create a default MimeMessage object.
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject(subject);

        // Now set the actual message
        message.setText(content);

        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
    } catch (AddressException e) {
        throw new Error("bad address");
    } catch (MessagingException e){
        throw new Error("bad message data");
    }
```

And my build looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
     compileSdkVersion 22
     buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.bsitpa.myfirstapp"
         minSdkVersion 15
         targetSdkVersion 22
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
     packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
     }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.5.3'
    //compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.5.0-b01'
    compile files('mail-1.5.0-b01.jar')
}
```

The debugging error:
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of Lcom/sun/mail/util/MailLogger"

And just so you know, I am completely new to AndroidStudio and Gradle.

Thanks a ton,
Ryan

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you solved this already, but I found you need to use an Android specific Java Mail library.

```
compile 'com.sun.mail:android-mail:1.5.5'
compile 'com.sun.mail:android-activation:1.5.5'
```

I was running into your error and other similar ones using the latest Java Mail libraries but switching to these fixed all of them.

https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Android

Answer (score -1):

In Module Settings, Dependencies, make sure libs is set to "Compile"

[image]